# crontab -e, permission denied after malware infection

Tags: permissions, cron, malware, xattr

**Caused by: My machine was infected with the redis mining worm**

Here are some files under `/root/.ssh` (it's hidden, using `ls -la` I can see it), I remove them and some other related files, hope it won't come again.

This gives me a lesson,next time I must set an access password for
redis and change the default port.

---

I'm trying to set my job under `root` user, when I run `crontab -e`, enter `:wq` without editing anything, I receive the following error message:

```
/var/spool/cron/#tmp.VM_0_2_centos.XXXXDJlSfY: Permission denied.
```

[image]

When I `chmod` the dir `/var/spool/cron/`, I get the `Operation not permitted` error:

[image]

List the attributes of `/var/spool/cron`, it's immutable.

[image]

When I use `chattr` to change it, no error but nothing been changed neither!

[image]

I reinstall cronie, it doesn't work. 
It drives me crazy now, I've no idea what else can I do to fix it.
Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Does `sudo crontab -e` work? Also, try to copy/paste the text from the terminal instead of adding images, it's the preferred format.

Comment: Your shell prompt includes the word `VM_0_2_centos` which looks like a hostname. That suggests you are on some sort of of a virtualized system. What kind of a virtualization platform is that, exactly? If your VM is some sort of a container and not a complete "classic" virtual machine, the immutability of `/var/spool/cron` might be a restriction imposed by the container management system.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani  thx for your reply. I am the root user ,sudo make no sence.
The problem caused by redis, I open redis on public network without change the default port 6379, nor do i set the password to access redis.  So my machine infected with the mining worm. I don't konw how to remove worm completed!

Comment: @NewSoul Your issue is a compromised machine, not a permission issue. You will need to take it off the internet ASAP, and then reinstall it. You could use the last known good backup to restore your data from. See e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments: A system should always be completely set up again after a malware infection. That means: A fresh OS installation.

In your case it is the worst case: Changing the `immutable` flag requires root privilege (or something close to that), and an attacker with root access can do everything to your system, including installing a rootkit or exchanging the `chattr` binary against a modified version. It is usually too difficult and too much effort to search for all modifications.

Redis should not run as `root` anyway.